# Get one of p tag value in td when tap on td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me.

I want to detect the tapping on td. But I also need to get the one of the p tag (cal_date) value when tapped.
How can I get the cal_date value?

JQUERY CURRENT CODE:

```
$( document ).on ( "tap", "td", function(event) { 
    //code here
    // i want to get the cal_date value in this block
});
```

I can't not use this way, because it will only can detect tap on the p.cal_date tag, not on the td tag...

```
$( document ).on ( "tap", ".cal_date", function(event) {

});
```

HTML:

```
<td><p class="cal_date" id="">7</p><br><p class="cal_rooms">16</p></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `.cal_date` element inside the tapped TD, and get it's text

```
$(document).on ("tap", "td", function(event) { 

    var value = $(this).find('.cal_date').text();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `tap` handler `this` refers to the tapped `td`element, so you can use `.find()` to get the `cal_date` element within it

```
$(document).on("tap", "td", function(event) {
  //code here
  // i want to get the cal_date value in this block
  var cal_date = $(this).find('.cal_date').text()
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want!